# asp.net mvc 4 tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project with Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net MVC4 (engine view Razor) and need to make a tabs.
I define this scrips and css:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
```

It also defines the format html for the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs"> .....
```

but when excecute don't showme the tabs, how I can solve this problem. only showme format html, this:

Index

Tab Header 1

Tab Header 2

Tab Header 3

Content for Tab 1 goes here.

Content for Tab 2 goes here.

Content for Tab 3 goes here.

Comment: show us what you have inside <div id="tabs">, it will help give you an answer

Comment: It is probably an overriding jQuery reference added to your HTML. I found this: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) tagged to the bottom of my HTML - which was wiping out the correct version that I referenced at the top, thas the .tabs() function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you work with ASP.net MVC4 then config _Layout.cshtml
add this lines into Head html

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")    
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

and delete from body (html) this line

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and execute the program and show the tabs

Answer (score 24):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/puXu5/) for Jquery Tabs.

**Step 1: Import**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Step 2: Html Code**

In the ‘li’ tags you need to define the tab header and for each tab header a tab content div exists, the code below is pretty self explanatory.

```
<div id="tabs">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab Header 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Header 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab Header 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
Content for Tab 1 goes here.<br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
Content for Tab 2 goes here.<br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
Content for Tab 3 goes here.<br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>

</div>
```

**Step 3: Final Touch – Jquery call to tabs()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[Source](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-jquery-ui-tab-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap 3.x solution:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab_1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1 goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2 goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3 goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add Bootstrap 3.x solution.
I encountered a problem using
*class=**"tab-pane fade active"** id="tab_1"*, the entries in tab_1 will not display upon page load.

Instead, I removed **fade** in the tab_1 (see below)

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1 goes here.</p>
</div>
```

or replace it with *class="tab-pane fade active **in**"*

It worked for me.