# Tab control not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to follow a basic [jquery tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) on how to call the tab object. Howver for the love of me I have had no luck getting it to render properly.

Instead of rendering with jQuery like it should, it shows up as plain text. like below

- area 1
- area 2
- area 3

Proin elit arcu

Morbi tincidunt

Mauris eleifend

I looked at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219874/asp-net-mvc-4-tabs) where the solution was adding some `@Styles.Render` and `@Scripts.Render` render to the `<head>` section and removing a `@Scripts.Render` from the `<body>`. But that did not do me any good.

Currently in my `_Layout.cshtml` the `<head>` looks like so.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>    
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

And at the bottom right before the `</body>` I have:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Elsewhere I do I have the @RenderBody call

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Built with ASP.NET MVC 4</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

The `Index.cshtml` I am trying to make the tab control in currently looks like.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>I will make a dynamic tab control here</h1>    
</div>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">area 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">area 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">area 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Web development makes me angry some days. My model and data layer section of my project was a breeze to make a test.

Comment: You're missing the `jQuery UI CSS` in your page header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MelanciaUK was partially right. My packages were messed up so I was missing style sheets and scripts. I put too much trust in Visual Studio.

I used NuGet to re-install the packages and then fixed my `BundleConfig.cs` to match.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"));
```

As was said in Monty Python, "And there was much rejoicing"

[image]